# Solution of $W_0(x)-W_{-1}(x)=1$

Tags: lambert-w

In my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2820180/best-linear-approximation-that-minimizes-the-following-l1-norm/2820366#2820366), $W(.)$ being Lambert function,  I indirectly showed that
$$W_0(x)-W_{-1}(x)=1 \implies x=-\frac {1} {e-1}\, \exp \left( \frac {-1} {e-1}\right)$$ Is there any way to prove it directly ?

**Edit after Szeto's answer**

Back [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2820180/best-linear-approximation-that-minimizes-the-following-l1-norm/2820366#2820366), this means that
$$W_0(x)=\frac{1}{1-e} \qquad \text{and}  \qquad W_{-1}(x)=\frac{e}{1-e}$$ which do not seem do appear as special values of Lambert function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the equation (1)(second page of the [paper](http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~djeffrey/Offprints/JeffreyJankowskiSYNASC2014.pdf))

If $d=W_0(z)-W_{-1}(z)$, 
$$\frac{d}{e^{-d}-1}\text{exp}\left(\frac{d}{e^{-d}-1}\right)=z$$

Here, $d=1$, and your result follows:

$$z=-\frac{e}{e-1}\text{exp}\left(\frac{e-1+1}{1-e}\right)=-\frac1{e-1} \text{exp}\left(\frac{1}{1-e}\right) $$

Proof of the equation:

*Note that $\text{(strange W)}_{mn}=W_m-W_n$(I spent a while to figure this out)*

[image]

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I am delighted that my answer is accepted by such a respectable user!

Comment: Are you kidding the old man ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Not too old because you know how to use a computer! :)

Comment: Thank you ! I appreciate. Just by curiosity, have a look to what was the largest computer in the world when I started computing in 1960. Cheers.

Comment: +1 for showing me a new reference for W

Answer (score 2):

Note that the inverse of $W$ is a rather simple function. Then we're looking for a value $x$ such that $$x e^x = (x+1)e^{x+1}$$ and this directly gives $$x = \frac{e}{1-e}.$$  So for $W$ we get the argument $$ \frac{e}{1-e}\exp\left(\frac{e}{1-e}\right) = \frac1{1-e}\exp\left(\frac{1}{1-e}\right).$$