# Inverse of $W_0(x)+W_{-1}(x)$ and $W_0(x)\times W_{-1}(x)$

Tags: approximation, inverse-function, parametrization, lambert-w

For $x\in(-\tfrac1{\mathrm{e}},0)$ and  $\alpha\in(0,1)$, defining
$$\large x=\alpha ^{\frac{\alpha }{1-\alpha }} \log \left(\alpha ^{\frac{\alpha }{1-\alpha }}\right)$$
the real branches of Lambert function can be parametrized as

$$W_0(x)=\frac{\alpha  \log (\alpha )}{1-\alpha }\qquad \text{and} \qquad W_{-1}(x)=\frac{ \log (\alpha )}{1-\alpha }$$

(have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3233107/parametric-representation-of-the-real-branches-operatornamew-0-operatorna)).

This allows to find interesting inverses (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2822658/solution-of-w-0x-w-1x-1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4625698/solving-a-ratio-of-lambert-w-branches-y-fracw-1xw-0x-where-y-is/4626803?noredirect=1#comment9760922_4626803))
$$y=W_0(x)-W_{-1}(x) \qquad \implies \qquad \large\color{blue}{x=\frac{y}{1-e^y} e^{\frac{y}{1-e^y}}}$$

$$y=\frac{W_{-1}(x)}{W_0(x)} \qquad \implies \qquad \large \color{blue}{ x=y^{\frac{1}{1-y}}\,\frac{\log(y)}{y-1}}$$

***What could we do for***
$$y=W_0(x)+W_{-1}(x)=\frac{1+\alpha  }{1-\alpha }\,\log (\alpha )\tag 1$$ and/or for
$$y=W_0(x)\times W_{-1}(x)=\frac{\alpha  }{(1-\alpha )^2}\,\log ^2(\alpha )\tag 2$$ even in terms of approximations.

For $(1)$, with $\alpha=e^t$, we have
$$e^{-t}=-\frac {t+y}{t-y}$$ which has a solution in terms of the generalized Lambert function.

For $(2)$, for a numerical solution
$$y \sim 1.1 (-e x)^{\frac 3{4}}-0.1 (-e x)^{\frac 3{2}}$$ gives a reasonable guess.

Comment: @TymaGaidash. Thank you but I already knew (not of much use however).

Comment: It may be small, but there is a [Burniston-Siewert](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0124048) solution to $a\sin(z)=z$