# Help me find the inverse of this function

Tags: recreational-mathematics, inverse-function, lambert-w

While working on a recreational math problem I have come to the point were I need to find the inverse of one of the two following functions;
$$\frac{W_0(x)(W_{-1}(x)+1)}{(W_0(x)+1)W_{-1}(x)}$$
$$\frac{(W_0(x)+1)W_{-1}(x)}{W_0(x)(W_{-1}(x)+1)}$$
Were $W$ is the LambertW function (the solution to $W(x)e^{W(x)}=x$, $W_0(x)$ are the real solutions where $W_0(x) > -1$ and $W_{-1}(x)$ are the real solutions where $W_{-1}(x) < -1$).
Looking at the graphs of both of the functions, the inverse of both appears to be the same function that is slightly less than $xe^x$ while $x$ is negative.  Wolfram times out when given these functions but can find the inverse of simpler functions in the same vain.  Sympy cannot handle it.  I am smart enough to simplify the problem I was working on downto this but I am not smart enough to take the inverse of these functions.

When I call this recreational math I mean that in the strictest possible sense of I am doing it for fun.  I have an undergrad degree in math and have spent 5 years on and off working on the greater problem that this is a part of in my free time.  I have learned a lot in researching bits and pieces of that problem and this question is no where near the final I will need to tackle in the greater problem.

Comment: I am not able to solve these problems, too, but maybe you are "reducing" the recreational math problem to a much more complicated higher math problem.

Comment: I assure you I am not.  When I say simplify here I mean it in the most literal possible way; the initial equation that lead me to this was a much greater mess of many LambertW functions

Comment: Related: [Inverse of $W_0(x)+W_{-1}(x)$ and $W_0(x)\times W_{-1}(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4627443/inverse-of-w-0xw-1x-and-w-0x-times-w-1x)

Comment: @Smasheded What is this “greater problem” that you have spent 5 years working on and off of? Also, using the parametrizations in the above link, and $\alpha=e^w$, the problem reduces to solving $w=-1-\frac2{y-1}+\left(1+\frac1{y-1}\right)e^w+\frac{e^{-w}}{y-1}$ where $y$ is the first function you want to invert.

Answer (score 1):

It could be interesting to use the parametrization of Lambert function (have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4627443/inverse-of-w-0xw-1x-and-w-0x-times-w-1x)).

For $x\in(-\tfrac1{\mathrm{e}},0)$  and $\alpha\in(0,1)$, defining

$$\color{blue}{\large x=\alpha ^{\frac{\alpha }{1-\alpha }} \log \left(\alpha ^{\frac{\alpha }{1-\alpha }}\right)}$$

the real branches of Lambert function can be parametrized as

$$\color{blue}{W_0(x)=\frac{\alpha  \log (\alpha )}{1-\alpha }}\qquad \text{and} \qquad \color{blue}{W_{-1}(x)=\frac{ \log (\alpha )}{1-\alpha }}$$

For the first function
$$y=\frac{W_0(x)\,(W_{-1}(x)+1)}{(W_0(x)+1)\,W_{-1}(x)}=\frac{\alpha  \left(\frac{\log (\alpha )}{1-\alpha
   }+1\right)}{\frac{\alpha  \log (\alpha )}{1-\alpha }+1}$$ which cannot be inversed but quite well approximated
by the $[n,n]$ Padé approximant $P_n$ built around $\alpha=1$

This would give

$$P_2= -\frac{11 \alpha ^2+18 \alpha +1}{\alpha ^2+18 \alpha +11}$$

$$P_3=-\frac{57 \alpha ^3+239 \alpha ^2+121 \alpha +3}{3 \alpha ^3+121
   \alpha ^2+239 \alpha +57}$$

$$P_4=-\frac{29 \alpha ^4+227 \alpha ^3+300 \alpha ^2+73 \alpha
   +1}{\alpha ^4+73 \alpha ^3+300 \alpha ^2+227 \alpha +29}$$

The respective errors of these approximants are
$$\frac{(\alpha -1)^5}{525} \qquad \qquad \frac{(\alpha -1)^7}{8820} \qquad \qquad \frac{(\alpha -1)^9}{145530}$$

Considering the infinite norm

$$\Phi_n=\int_0^1 \Bigg( \frac{\alpha  \left(\frac{\log (\alpha )}{1-\alpha
   }+1\right)}{\frac{\alpha  \log (\alpha )}{1-\alpha }+1}-P_n  \Bigg)^2\, d \alpha$$ they are

$$\Phi_2=1.99614\times 10^{-4} \quad\quad \Phi_3=3.70724\times 10^{-5} \quad\quad \Phi_4=1.01236\times 10^{-5}$$

So, at the price of a quadratic, cubic or quartic equation, we can have an *approximate* value of $\alpha$ and then $x$ from its definition.

A few numbers (using the chain $x\to \alpha \to y \to \alpha \to x$)
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
x & x_{(2)} & x_{(3)} & x_{(4)} \\
 -0.15 & -0.113812 & -0.140978 & -0.147205 \\
 -0.20 & -0.185725 & -0.197052 & -0.199294 \\
 -0.25 & -0.245433 & -0.249309 & -0.249885 \\ 
 -0.30 & -0.299159 & -0.299925 & -0.299993 \\
 -0.35 & -0.349985 & -0.350000 & -0.350000 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Using $P_3$, the cubic to be solved for $\alpha$ is
$$3 (y+19)\, \alpha ^3+ (121 y+239)\,\alpha ^2+  (239 y+121)\,\alpha+3(19y+1)=0$$

With
$$p=\frac{10 (1249 y^2+1588 y+3643}{27 (y+19)^2}$$
$$q=\frac{40 (69404 y^3+118731 y^2+222576 y+318289)}{729 (y+19)^3}$$ the *approximate* solution is
$$\alpha=2 \sqrt{\frac{p}{3}}\cos \left(\frac{1}{3} \cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{3 \sqrt{3} q}{2p^{\frac 32} }\right)\right)-\frac{121 y+239}{9 (y+19)}$$

Another thing which could be done is a series expansion around $\alpha=1$ followed by a power series reversion yo obtain
$$\alpha=1-t +\frac {t^2}6 \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\,t^n \qquad \text{where} \qquad t= \frac 32(1+y)$$ the very first coefficients being

$$\left\{1,\frac{2}{15},\frac{1}{36},\frac{71}{9450},\frac{281}{11340
   0},\frac{29}{30375},\frac{16859}{40824000},\frac{36557}{18860688
   0},\frac{27230983}{282910320000}\right\}$$

Using the above terms, for $\alpha=\frac 1e$, the exact value is $y=  -\frac{1}{(e-2) e}$ and the recomputed value is $\alpha=\color{red}{0.367879}001$